# How to redirect a url to another url using web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I would like to redirect https://www.test.com/flights/economy-class-flights to https://www.test.com/flight-types/economy-class

And I tried something like below and it didn't work.

```
<rule name="Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="https://www.test.com/flights/economy-class-flights" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.test.com/flight-types/economy-class" /></rule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web config - redirect specific url with domain to another url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754796/web-config-redirect-specific-url-with-domain-to-another-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
<rule name="redirect RedirectURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^flights/economy-class-flights" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?test.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/flight-types/economy-class" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```